# Cannot Access rgb properties of Vec4 in Fragment Shader OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I have a simple fragment shader in which i pass two textures. I tested outputting both textures and they were correct (ie, what i inputed)

**HOWEVER**, when I try to access the rgb properties of a texture (converted into a `vec4`) the program gives an error of glerror 1282 (Invalid operation)

**✘** The following shader crashes:

```
    #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture2;
    uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;

    void main() {
        vec4 originalrgb = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
        vec4 floodfillimage = vec4((texture2D(sTexture2, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);

        vec4 c = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1); /*Blue Tint Colour*/
        vec4 inputColor = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
        float average = (inputColor.r + inputColor.g + inputColor.b) / 3.0;
        vec4 grayscale = vec4(average, average, average, 1.0);
        vec4 colorizedOutput = grayscale * c;

        vec4 test;
        if(floodfillimage.r > 0.9){ /*This is what makes it crash, cant seem to access the rgb properties of this*/
            test = colorizedOutput.rgba;
        }else{
            test = originalrgb.rgba;
        }

        gl_FragColor = test;
    }
```

---

**✔** This one does NOT Crash

```
    #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
    precision mediump float;
    /*
    * Original Camera Frame Image
    */
    varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture2;
    uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
    void main() {
        vec4 originalrgb = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
        vec4 floodfillimage = vec4((texture2D(sTexture2, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);

        vec4 c = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1); /*Blue Tint Colour*/
        vec4 inputColor = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
        float average = (inputColor.r + inputColor.g + inputColor.b) / 3.0;
        vec4 grayscale = vec4(average, average, average, 1.0);
        vec4 colorizedOutput = grayscale * c;

        gl_FragColor = floodfillimage;
    }
```

---

**✔** This one does NOT Crash as well.

```
    #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
    precision mediump float;
    /*
    * Original Camera Frame Image
    */
    varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture2;
    uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
    void main() {
        vec4 originalrgb = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
        vec4 floodfillimage = vec4((texture2D(sTexture2, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);

        vec4 c = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1); /*Blue Tint Colour*/
        vec4 inputColor = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
        float average = (inputColor.r + inputColor.g + inputColor.b) / 3.0;
        vec4 grayscale = vec4(average, average, average, 1.0);
        vec4 colorizedOutput = grayscale * c;

        gl_FragColor = originalrgb;
    }
```

---

**✔** This one does NOT Crash as well.

```
    #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
    precision mediump float;
    /*
    * Original Camera Frame Image
    */
    varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture2;
    uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
    void main() {
        vec4 originalrgb = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
        vec4 floodfillimage = vec4((texture2D(sTexture2, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);

        vec4 c = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1); /*Blue Tint Colour*/
        vec4 inputColor = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
        float average = (inputColor.r + inputColor.g + inputColor.b) / 3.0;
        vec4 grayscale = vec4(average, average, average, 1.0);
        vec4 colorizedOutput = grayscale * c;

        gl_FragColor = colorizedOutput;
    }
```

Why does it crash when I want to access the 'r', 'g' or 'b' properties of the texture?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
Accessing the properties and assigning them directly to `gl_Fragcolor` works. ie, the following works:

```
gl_FragColor.r = floodfillimage.r;
gl_FragColor.g = floodfillimage.g;
gl_FragColor.b = floodfillimage.b;
gl_FragColor.a = floodfillimage.a;
```

Comment: If you get GL errors depending on the shader code, either the shaders fail to compile or link (and you should check the respective logs for the error messages), or your code changes trigger some changes in the OpenGL state. E.g., the non-working variant is the only one which has both sampler uniforms active, so you might just screwed up your uniform variable setup, or don't properly use multiple texture units.

Comment: I'm not getting any compile or link error (passes all the initialization), I didn't setup sampler uniforms in my code because they are two different type and I'm using GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureId); for the first one and GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id3); for the other texture @derhass

Comment: "I didn't setup sampler uniforms in my code because they are two different type and I'm using [different texture targets of the same texture unit]" And exactly that is _not_ allowed in OpenGL.  While you can have multiple textures of different type bound to the same unit, you can only sampe from texture target per texture unit in each draw call.

Comment: Can the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` be treated the same as `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, as in using active texture? ie, `GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);` can this be used with `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` @derhass

Comment: It can be used with any kind of texture object.